# Get Byte Size of Individual Log in Log Insights

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am looking at a given LogGroup within the Log Insights.
I can filter the logs by a field.
e.g.

```
fields @message
| sort @timestamp desc
| filter time < 3
```

How can I find out how much much data actually corresponds to the found logs though?
It tells me how many logs it scanned to find these logs, but I can't seem to find out how much data actually matches the logs that match the query makes up?